# Free software CRM, with RTL support, for local work (without internet connection)?

Tags: crm

I need a Free software CRM, with RTL (right to left writing) support, for local work.

It should be suitable at least for Windows10, but I cross-platform is the best.

Features I need for each customer card:

- Check-marking problems the customer has (I will define the problems myself in the system).
- Documentation of a session by free typing on the keyboard.
- Notes for the customer.
- Each customer will have a directory/folder in the PC itself with files associated with him (it would best if I could access these from the program).

Basically it should be very basic, very minimal software.

Comment: What do you mean by "RTL"?

Comment: Right to left. Will now edit.